# In Python, how do I draw/ save a monochrome 2 bit BMP with Wand

Tags: python, wand

I have a need to create a 2 bit monochrome Windows BMP format image, and need to draw lines in a pattern. Since I have just started using python, I followed a tutorial and installed the [Wand module](https://docs.wand-py.org/en/0.6.7/).

Drawing is fine, I get the content I need.

Problem is saving the image. No matter what I do, the resulting image is always 24 bpp BMP.

What I have so far:

```py
from wand.image import Image
from wand.drawing import Drawing
from wand.color import Color
draw=Drawing()

### SET VARS
mystepvalue = 15

with Image(filename='empty.bmp') as image:
          print(image.size)
          image.antialias = False
          draw.stroke_width = 1
          draw.stroke_color = Color('black')
          draw.fill_color = Color('black')
          #
          # --- draw the lines ---
          #
          for xpos in range(0,4790,mystepvalue):
                    draw.line( (xpos,0), (xpos, image.height) )

          draw(image)  # Have to remember this to see anything...

          # None of this makes a 2bit BMP
          image.depth = 2
          image.colorspace = "gray"
          image.antialias = False
          image.monochrome = True
          image.imagedepth =2
          image.save(filename='result.bmp')
```

Source image is 4800 x 283 px 169kb, result.bmp is same, but 4.075 kb.

It's probably the order of the color settings that I miss.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using [`Image.quantize()`](https://docs.wand-py.org/en/0.6.7/wand/image.html#wand.image.BaseImage.quantize) to remove all the unique gray colors before setting the depth/colorspace properties.

```py
    # ...
    image.quantize(2, colorspace_type='gray', dither=True)
    image.depth = 2
    image.colorspace = 'gray'
    image.type = 'bilevel'  # or grayscale would also work.
    image.save(filename='result.bmp')
```

Also remember `filename='bmp3:result.bmp'` or `filename='bmp2:result.bmp'` controls which BMP version to encode with.

Comment: I tried your solution and different variants. The only thing that did the trick is `image.type = 'bilevel'`. Leaving this out made image 24bit, keeping it (and not the others) worked. I'll accept your solution none the less.   I wonder if there is a "native" python way to paint in pixels, without ImageMagick.

Comment: Use numpy to draw the pixels on a 2d matrix. Then import the data into Wand, or Pillow, when your ready to encode into a image format.

Comment: Now, how do I turn this into a 4 bits png ?

Answer (score 0):

For me setting image mode to "1" did the job:

```
img.mode='1'
img.save('result.bmp')
```

Here are the docs on different modes: https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/stable/handbook/concepts.html#concept-modes